# Is my code a 'safe' singleton?

Tags: java, android, singleton

I was wondering if my code will produce a true singleton.  I am creating an Android app, and all activities should access my API through one instance of the `SyncApi` class.

```
public class Api {

    private static SyncApi api = null;

    static {
        synchronized (api) {
            if (api == null) {
                api = new ApiFActory().getSyncApi();
            }
        }
    }

    public static SyncApi getInstance() {
        return api;
    }
}
```

Use of the class would look like:

```
SyncApi api = Api.getInstance();
api.logOn("jjnguy", "pa55w0rd");
```

Comment: If you don’t want laziness, why not initialise the `SyncApi` instance directly in the declaration? No need for the `static` constructor. Java guarantees that initialisation of static members will only happen once.

Comment: @Konrad, ah!  Well that helps then.  I was worried that the initialization could (in rare multi-threaded cases) happen more than once.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that Singletons are considered an anti-pattern mostly now due to the difficulty in testing. Also you haven't made the constructor private so this isn't actually a Singleton.

Comment: Here synchronization may not works correctly, all is explained in Effective Java from Joshua Bloch, or some sample in Wikipedia

Comment: @Athas Singletons are considered an anti-pattern because it takes this nice concept of encapsulation and controlled flow of data and says "hey, let's go back to having global variables now.".

Comment: Why why why you init a `static` variable to null ? It will be null - will be even if not static - bad idiom

Comment: `synchronized (null)` is mutch more effective way to create a NPE and prevent the loading of the class. BTW: The NPE will be absolutly thread-save.

Answer (score 42):

In Java there’s an established idiom for creating a [thread-safe singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), due to Bill Pugh:

```
public class Api {
    private Api() { }

    private static class SingletonHolder { 
        public static final SyncApi INSTANCE = new ApiFactory().getSyncApi();
    }

    public static SyncApi getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

This implementation is both *lazy* and completely *thread-safe*, without the need to explicit synchronization and checking. This has the advantage that it eliminates the possibility of subtle race conditions and redundant locking.

Comment: How is the `SyncApi` class defined? I believe this implementation can be broken if `Api` and/or `SyncApi` are not `final`. One could extend these classes and create objects in ways completely uncontrolled by this code. Every instance of `SyncApi`'s subclass would obviously be an instance of `SyncApi` as well. The enum-based solution is not affected by this because all enums are implicitly final.

Comment: @Tom Actually I just copied & pasted OP’s code to some extent, I was actually meaning the two classes to be one (i.e. `SyncApi` = `Api`), then this code is safe (`Api` cannot be extended).

Comment: OK, I missed the `private` constructor being the only one. `final` wouldn't hurt for clarity though.

Comment: **Don’t use this code** — use the enum-based safe singleton idiom given in the answer by user aivikiss.

Answer (score 37):

The best and simple method was gived by Joshua Bloch in *《Effective Java 2th edition》*

```
public enum Api {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

you can use it like this

```
Api api = Api.INSTANCE;
```

Comment: This is not at all a singleton.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  Enums are different from singletons.

Comment: Why?  Enums are classes, are they not?  If you define additional non-static methods on the Api class above, it will behave exactly like a singleton, because it IS a singleton.

Comment: @rom, good point.  I'd like to see this example expanded upon.

Answer (score 4):

If you want thread-safe and lazy, I completely agree with the [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1673/is-my-code-a-safe-singleton/1675#1675) provided by Konrad Rudolph.

If you want just thread-safe without laziness (which is also very common), then you can initialize INSTANCE in the upper class, not from inner one.

Here is a good article with many tests and examples:
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html

But both approaches don't give you an absolute singleton, since different ClassLoaders will create different instances. It might look like a nearly impossible case, but in my experience I faced a bug which was cause by such a situation.

Here is an article about absolute singletons:
http://surguy.net/articles/communication-across-classloaders.xml

Comment: Yes - he must use an enum to have an absolute singleton

Answer (score 4):

Your setting your api to null did not help you spot your NullPointerException

```
synchronized (api) // api == null, you should use Api.class
```

As to the singleton please, please, *please* use an enum. [It is the recommended pattern since java 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71399/281545). Now, [if you want lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883051/enum-and-singletons-top-level-vs-nested-enum) :

```
public class Api {

    private Api() {}

    private enum SingletonHolder {
        INSTANCE;

        private static final Api singleton = new Api();

        Api getSingleton() {
            return singleton;
        }
    }

    public Api api() {
        Api.SingletonHolder.INSTANCE.getSingleton();
    }
}
```

Call :

```
 api().logOn("jjnguy", "pa55w0rd");
```

You may dispose of `getSingleton()` and access `singleton` directly inside `Api`

```
public class Api {

    private Api() {/*your costly init here*/}

    private enum SingletonHolder {
        INSTANCE;
        private static final Api singleton = new Api();
    }

    public Api api() {
        return Api.SingletonHolder.singleton;
    }
}
```

Comment: you do not need to use `static` and `final` keywords in enum class declaration as enum classes are already provide `static` and `final`.

Comment: @EnesUnal: correct (see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/253282/281545), edited

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is definitely not a Singleton, because this code is legal:
`Api.api=new Api();`

You should *at least* define api variable as final and at least private constructor to avoid instantiation.

See @Konrad Rudolph's for proposed solution.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with all the other answers but your problem, as you state it, is not to have a single API instance but to have a single SyncApi instance.

You will have no way to prevent a user from doing:

```
SyncApi api = new ApiFActory().getSyncApi();
```

You have to make SyncApi a Singleton or encapsulate it's usage in your Api class and not give access to it outside your Api...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Singleton {
      private static Singleton instance = null;

      public static Singleton getInstance(){
         if(null == instance){
          synchronized(Singleton.class){
             //double check
               if(null == instance){
                instance = new Singleton();
              }
           }  
         }
         return instance;
       }

}
```

This can be used to ensure only single instance is created. Or just use Enums.

Comment: `if(null == instance)` Yoda-style, this sounds like.